# java hibernate - alias in query not found

Tags: java, hibernate, alias

I've this query in my dao

```
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT geoCity,(CASE WHEN geoCity.name LIKE :search1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as myOrder FROM GeoCity geoCity    WHERE (LOWER(geoCity.name) LIKE :search ) ORDER BY geoCity.myOrder ,geoCity.name");
```

this is entity

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * GeoCity generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="geo_city" ,schema="public")
public class GeoCity  implements java.io.Serializable {
    .....

     public transient Integer myOrder;

    public GeoCity() {
    }

    public GeoCity(String istat) {
        this.istat = istat;
    }


    @Transient
    public Integer getMyOrder() {
        return myOrder;
    }

    public void setMyOrder(Integer myOrder) {
        this.myOrder = myOrder;
    }
}
```

geoRegion.myOrder is not valid. but i need to use case when inside my query to order in specific way. is there a way?

Comment: sorry bad copy & past

Answer (score 0):

it's because your declaration is `transient`.

```
public transient Integer myOrder; // this is transient
```

try to remove `transient`.

```
public Integer myOrder;
```

and remove your annotation `@Transient` in your method.

**Transient** means, The variable you declared is **not** `serializable` that's why it is an invalid input in hibernate. Click this link for more info in **[Transient Keyword](http://www.javatpoint.com/transient-keyword)**.

Comment: but unless you use transient happens that when I try to insert a record, it says that my Myorder column does not exist? I remember well. Now I can not prove why the code is on my home pc but tonight I check.

Comment: `myOrder` column doesn't exist in hibernate because you use `transient` on that field, meaning that will not be apart of your serialization to hibernate. you can only use `myOrder` variable inside your code but it can't be serialize by hibernate unless you remove transient on it.

Comment: if I do not use transient I get the following error message 'Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column geocity0_.myorder does not exist'

Comment: dont use `@Transient`, use `@Column` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I post alternative solution using native query

```
public ArrayList<Autocomplete> autocomplete(String search, HttpSession httpSession, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ArrayList<Autocomplete> autocomplete = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT istat,name,CASE WHEN LOWER(g.name) LIKE :search1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as myOrder FROM geo_city g WHERE (LOWER(g.name) LIKE :search ) ORDER BY myOrder, g.name");
        q.setParameter("search","%" + search.toLowerCase()  + "%");
        q.setParameter("search1",search.toLowerCase()  + "%");
        List<Object[]> city = q.getResultList();
        if(city!=null && city.size()>0){
            for(Object[] o: city) {
                autocomplete.add(new Autocomplete(o[0].toString(), o[1].toString()));
            }
        }else{
            autocomplete.add(new Autocomplete("","Nessun risultato!"));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return autocomplete;
}
```